# exclude in ModelAdmin vs ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform, modeladmin

Is the exclude list in a ModelForm any different from an exclude list in a ModelAdmin? If my ModelForm is tied to the ModelAdmin, where do I need to specify the exclude list ideally; in the ModelForm Meta class or in the ModelAdmin subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you want to do something else with the form. If its displayed somewhere else than the admin and you want to exclude the same field there as well, define it in the ModelForm. If the ModelForm is just used in the admin and nowhere else you basically can choose what makes more sense for you. I personally would still keep it in the ModelForm so this functionality is tied to it instead to the admin.

**Edit** (see comments below):

Apparently there seems to be a bug in Django. If I exclude something in a ModelForm and then use this form in the ModelAdmin it is still showing this field for some reason. You better exclude in the admin only to be 100% sure or specify `fields` in the ModelForm without the field you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Does one override the other if it is in both places?

Comment: Don't do it at both places. If you exclude a field in a ModelForm and then bind this form to the ModelAdmin and exclude the same field again it will raise an `ImproperlyConfigured` Exception. It will try to exclude a field which is already excluded in the form and fail (since it can not find this field). You can of course exclude other fields in the Admin which were not excluded in the form before.

Comment: I tried this whole thing just now with Django 1.3 stable and it seems like there is a bug in ModelForm.exclude. When I exclude a field and then use this form in the ModelAdmin it is (in my case) still showing this field in the admin. If I specify `fields` as well in the ModelForm it will not show the missing fields though. I edited my answer above to keep this in mind.

Comment: Happens for me too. I am sticking to exclude in modelAdmin for now. Will try pursuing a ticket for this once I test a bit more. Thanks for looking into this.